# asynchronous simultaneus tasks in python

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python processes, and I'm trying to write something for the following scenario using the multiprocessing module:

I want to collect frames from a camera (webcam or other) and simultaneously do some processing on a "stack" of a previously collected sequence. The thing is, I want to achieve the highest frame rate possible, with losing as little frames as possible. I was thinking of using one process to collect a specified number of frames, save them in an array and send it to a second process which performs an analysis on that array, and in the meantime the first process continues to collect frames, and continuously toggle between these two processes. 
Obviously there will be some frames lost while waiting for the second process to become available again, but the whole point is to lower these to a minimum. I'm assuming that the data analysis will take more time than the frame acquisition.

Any ideas on what will be the best/most efficient way to do this ?
Also - whats the best way to store and transfer the data between processes ? will using a queue help ?
Is there any benefit to using a "class" to define each process ?

Comment: You should read up on the [Python GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) before going anywhere near async or multithreading. After that, there are some async functionality in the standard library, take a look at them.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the `threading` module which is built-in and fairly easy to use for beginners.

Here's a quick example:

```
import threading
def get_image():
    #Grab a frame from the camera.

def process_image():
    #Process the image(s).

threading.Thread(target=get_image).start()
threading.Thread(target=process_image).start()
```

That code will cause both functions to run in separate threads simultaneously. [This](https://pymotw.com/2/threading/) article goes more in-depth about how to use the `threading` module efficiently.